# Apply values in HKEY Depending on the selected language with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

Here is my project, where I have added `Languages: english` / `Languages: spanish` but is not working. Any idea if I'm doing something wrong?

Only the English value is applied even if I have chosen Spanish in the Inno Setup installer:

- `00000000` is english code value
- `00000004` is spanish code value

```
[Languages]
Name: english; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\english.isl"
Name: spanish; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\spanish.isl"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: SOFTWARE\ProgramTell\softell101.exe; ValueType: string; Languages: english; \
  ValueName: Language; ValueData: 00000000
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: SOFTWARE\ProgramTell\softell101.exe; ValueType: string; Languages: spanish; \
  ValueName: Language; ValueData: 00000004
```

Comment: I use this logic in my installer script and it works fine.

Comment: Run your installer from the command line in a console window and use the log switch to create a log file. This will show what the installer is doing.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Yes, 32-bit registry in windows x64, I have verified that the value is saved, only that the software is not translated, I have also verified by going directly to the registry editor and when I click on language the value is 0, when it should be 4 of the selected Spanish language, when I save the value it looks like this: 0x00000004 (4), and works great but I still don't know why this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @Martin and to all of you guys, I have solved it by changing to ValueType: dword;